# How to show display modal even if there is an id in URL?

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

I have this `http://localhost/student/stud.php?id=1` in my URL since I get id of the following student. When I hover on my modal, it will not display because of this URL in the status bar: `http://localhost/student/stud.php?id=1#modal`. Any help? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add some code here, we can help you without some code

Comment: add your code here.

Comment: Show relevant code of your modal trigger and be sure you haven't used the `id` of that particular modal for another modal. No two modals should have the same `id` attr (#modal)

Comment: I just want to get the id when the link is hover, the modal will display if there is no id in url. @Jalpesh?

Comment: I want to remove the id in the url  once i hover on the link, so that it will produce a result of http://localhost/student/stud.php#1

Comment: why are you sending us your localhost url?  we can't access it as the name stated "localhoast" its on your machine only

Answer (score 0):

Check if the url has an ID using the GET method. Below is an example.

```
   <?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) { ?>
          <div class="modal fade in" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="display: block;">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
    ?>
```

Comment: It has an id, its working on the other page. But with the URL in the status bar that has an id, it will not show up. ?id=1 it will product a ?id=1#1. Any help? thanks in advance.